# How do I join values from different object array from a json response? Node.js, Discord.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, object, discord.js

So this is a JSON response from an api wrapper npm package

```
    [
      { 
       name: Dank Memer
       id  : 10111
      },

      { 
        name: Poketwo
        id  : 10122
      },
     
      { 
       name: Mudae
       id  : 10445
     }
]
```

This data is stored in a variable **resp** and look like this:

```
    discord.bots.get(function (err, resp) {
   if(err) { throw err } 
   else {
    console.log(resp)
    } 
})
```

What I need is, I want my bot to send a single message that includes all the three names from the array.
Like:

```
Dank Memer
Poketwo
Mudae
```

I have tried to use **.forEach()** but when I used it, the bot showed all the names, but in different messages, each containing each **name** from the JSON.
I tried **.join()** too, but it didn't work.

So that's it, how do I join the names from the JSON response?

Comment: What data exactly are you “joining” here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way would just be:

```js
resp.map(({ name }) => name).join('\n');
```

This will map each element by its `name` property and then join all three by a new line.

```js
const resp = [
  {
    name: 'Dank Memer',
    id: 10111,
  },
  {
    name: 'Poketwo',
    id: 10122,
  },
  {
    name: 'Mudae',
    id: 10445,
  },
];

const names = resp.map(({ name }) => name).join('\n');
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do something like that?

```
discord.bots.get(function (err, resp) {
   if(err) { throw err } 
   else {
    let names = "";
    resp.forEach( user => { names += user.name + '\n\r' } )
    console.log(names)
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single line return based on answer from Lioness100

```js
const resp = [
  {
    name: 'Dank Memer',
    id: 10111,
  },
  {
    name: 'Poketwo',
    id: 10122,
  },
  {
    name: 'Mudae',
    id: 10445,
  },
];

const names = resp.map((item) => { return item.name })
console.log(names.toString());
```